# html dynamic <input list>

Tags: html, ajax

```
 <input list="browsers" name="browser" />
 <datalist id="Names">
 <option value="AD">
 <option value="AB">
 <option value="CD">
 <option value="DA">
 <option value="EB">
 </datalist>
```

when a user starts typing the input then it should connect to the database and should fetch the results and should show in the drop down menu.

Not sure which language to be used to fulfill the need

Is there any way to figure this out??

Thanks in advance

Comment: What server-side language are you using?

Comment: I want a button on SO that automatically adds a "So what have you tried?" comment

Comment: @BrianAgnew: http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se

Comment: @Truth - that'll save *hours* out of my day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're automatically generating this HTML at the server side, then can I suggest you check out [Java Server Pages](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/JSPIntro.html) for the HTML generation, and [JDBC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/) for the database side. You'd use JDBC to talk to the database and pull out the suitable values, and the JSPs to render into HTML and present this.

As you need some AJAX capability, can I point you to [DWR](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html), which provides a very nice framework for exposing Java objects in the browser and will handle this sort of stuff.

Comment: Sure i will check out Java Server Pages and JDBC to communicate with Mysql Database ( Had a little knowledge in both )

Comment: What i actually want is.. when a user start typing some input i want to connect to database and fetch the results and  display the suggestions like a drop down menu.

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that what you want to do is autocompletion in a search box or something similar. In that case, you will need to use javascript to detect the changes on client side and send it to the server which return results in JSON format. Then, convert JSON into html options. Here is some useful tools and concept using jquery http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/

Answer (score -1):

Use PHP:

```
<input list="browsers" name="browser" />
 <datalist id="Names">
 <?php
    // query the database and store the options in the array $names
    foreach($names as $name) {
        echo "<option value=" . $name . ">";
    }
 ?>
 </datalist>
```

Comment: Given he's tagged this with Java, I really don't think this is suitable

Comment: @Silox Iam new to programing as i googled if i want to use PHP i need to hard code my database credentials in the code which i dont want to do it. so is there any other way arround....

Comment: @BrianAgnew Sorry i thought it can be done with java (My bad)